# Should this question be tagged C++ as well?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

The question [What do numbers using 0x notation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean) currently only has the C tag. Yet all the answers would apply uniformaly to C++ as well.

It looks like a good canonical for both languages, indeed [one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean#comment90289255_8186965) even adds:

> Searching for 0x prefix C++ brings you here now :)

Adding the tag therefore looks appropriate to me. Does the community agree?

---

As a motivating example for this post, consider this existing [question about octals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568200/what-is-special-about-numbers-starting-with-zero). It's tagged for both, and that seems to work well there.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure, IMO a good canonical should list all possibilities of creating literal numbers (including prefixed `0` for oktal numbers) which are common for c and c++. In general this question would be OK to have both tags, since the literal building is common in this case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - There is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568200/what-is-special-about-numbers-starting-with-zero) for octals. It's tagged for both. I don't see why we can't have a canonical for each literal type if they already exist (writing them from scratch now would be kinda daft, yes).

Comment: Let's not, that never ends.  There are a lot of languages that have adopted the 0x prefix.  Google sorts it out well enough, second hit is the C/C++ language :)

Comment: @Hans Ouch o_O ... you said _"the C/C++ language"_ :D

Comment: @HansPassant - I'm only asking because of the C/C++ nature of the question for octals. I mean, this hex question exists, it's a prime dupe candidate for both C and C++ (where this is asked fairly often). Should it not be tagged appropriately? If only to match the tags when closing against it?

Comment: It is really necessary to give such a question the exalted status of a duplicate?  One that needs to be kept because it might cover Google queries?  Seems quite unlikely after a decade of questions about it.  If you want to help then just a link to the canonical ought to be good enough.

Comment: @HansPassant - No, I want to give it the exalted status of a canonical about hexadecimal literals because it's clear, on point and asks *only* about the literals. The indexing by google is just a cherry on top.

Comment: If it's actually agnostic, then the correct action would be removing tags, not adding more.

Comment: @Braiam Well, one more would need to be added: [tag:language-agnostic].

Comment: @Dukeling I'm suer you mean replacing.